# Redis Pub/Sub memory consumption

Tags: memory, redis, publish-subscribe, system-design

I’m currently reading System Design Interview, an insider guide vol2 by Alex Xu & Sahn Lam and I’m a bit struggling on understanding the way they calculated Redis Pub/Sub memory consumption

The calculations I’m interested in is in Chapter 2, Design Deep Dive section, How many Redis Pus/Sub servers do we need?

They say “it takes about 20 bytes of pointers in the internal hash table and linked list to track each subscriber” and I do not completely understand how did they get this number 20? What is the way or formula to calculate it?

I will appreciate any help such as references materials or any explanation